# Adjusting the formula in formulaarray

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following formula which i want to enter in formulaarray but am not able to do so due to size limitations.

```
=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS('S:\AT Reports\Abhor - Ganganagar\[1 1550 A-B.xls]1 1550 A-B'!$C$17:$C$42-B5*1000)=MIN(ABS('S:\AT Reports\Abhor - Ganganagar\[1 1550 A-B.xls]1 1550 A-B'!$C$17:$C$42-B5*1000)),IF(ABS('S:\AT Reports\Abhor - Ganganagar\[1 1550 A-B.xls]1 1550 A-B'!$C$17:$C$42-B5*1000)< 500,'S:\AT Reports\Abhor - Ganganagar\[1 1550 A-B.xls]1 1550 A-B'!$C$17:$C$42,))),'S:\AT Reports\Abhor - Ganganagar\[1 1550 A-B.xls]1 1550 A-B'!$C$17:$E$42,3,FALSE)
```

What you see above is the result of the VBA program. The actual formula in the VBA code is as follows:

```
formulaValue = "=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS('" & initpath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B.xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B'!$C$17:$C$42-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)=MIN(ABS('" & initpath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B.xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B'!$C$17:$C$42-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)),IF(ABS('" & initpath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B.xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B'!$C$17:$C$42-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)< 500,'" & initpath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B.xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B'!$C$17:$C$42,))),'" & initpath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B.xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B'!$C$17:$E$42,3,FALSE)"

            ActiveCell.Formula = formulaValue
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: what size limitations? do you get an error? if yes, please show the error. do not add extra info in comments, but update (edit) your question instead, to keep it always complete.

Comment: @hoijui The `FormulaArray` property is limited to 255 characters.

Comment: Cant Balinti....... in S:\AT Reports\Abhor - Ganganagar[1 1550 A-B.xls], the value before 1550 changes from 1 to 56 and then 1550 itself changes thrice in total and A-B changes to B-A...
So I have file names like
S:\AT Reports\Abhor - Ganganagar[1 1550 A-B.xls]
S:\AT Reports\Abhor - Ganganagar[56 1625 B-A.xls]
S:\AT Reports\Abhor - Ganganagar[34 1310 A-B.xls]

Comment: @PatricK: Please do not amend the tags. VBA tag is for code which is applicable across other Office Platforms like Word/Powerpoint/Access etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FormulaArray` has a 255 characters limit.

You will have to split up the `Formula` and `Replace` parts to make it whole again.
See code below:

```
Dim Formula As String
Dim fLoc As String

Formula = "=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS($C$17:$C$42-B5*1000)=MIN(ABS($C$17:$C$42-B5*1000)),IF(ABS($C$17:$C$42-B5*1000)< 500,$C$17:$C$42,))),$C$17:$E$42,3,FALSE)"


fLoc = "'S:\AT Reports\Abhor - Ganganagar\[1 1550 A-B.xls]1 1550 A-B'!$C$17"

With ActiveCell
    .FormulaArray = Formula
    .Replace "$C$17", fLoc   
End With
```

**Edit:**

After your update about your `Formula` this is how to do it with Variables:

```
Formula = "=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS($C$17:$C$42-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)=MIN(ABS($C$17:$C$42-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)),IF(ABS($C$17:$C$42-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)< 500,$C$17:$C$42,))),$C$17:$E$42,3,FALSE)"

fLoc = "'" & initpath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B.xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B'!$C$17"

With ActiveCell
    .FormulaArray = Formula
    .Replace "$C$17", fLoc  
End With
```

Comment: That's a pretty good trick although I might have removed all of the path/workbook and worksheet then replaced `$C$17:` with the `<full_path>!$C$17:`.

Comment: @Jeeped that is what I did right? Or I am misunderstanding what you mean o.O. Edit: ahhh I get it now, yea that would also work :)

Comment: doesnt work. get the following error
Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range Class.
Does that imply that i am still exceeding the 255 char limit?

Comment: @Jeeped always like your posts :), and your canadian! :)

Comment: @ShikharParashar did you try exactly as mentioned in my answer? The code is tried and tested with no problems besides that I don't have the file myself

Comment: flocA2B = (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B.xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & " A-B'"                             formulavalue = "=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS('_Loc_!$C$17:$C$42-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)=MIN(ABS('_Loc_!$C$17:$C$42-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)),IF(ABS('_Loc_'!$C$17:$C$42-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)< 500,'_Loc_'!$C$17:$C$42,))),'_Loc_'!$C$17:$E$42,3,FALSE)"
               
                ActiveCell.FormulaArray = formulavalue
                With ActiveCell
                    .FormulaArray = formulavalue
                    .Replace "_Loc_", flocA2B
                End With

Comment: Have removed the use of initpath variable as that will not be required if formulaArray is working. If i have to use the Formula option, then i need the path because once the program closes all the files, I have to use Crtl+shift+enter to show the values in excel

Comment: @ShikharParashar you do `ActiveCell.FormulaArray = formulavalue` and then you do the same in the `With` statement

Comment: @ShikharParashar please first test if the code given to you works and then try to adjust as needed :)

Comment: Have taken care of that.... I too am trying to find a solution... hence you see that here.... but i did realize that mistake in the code and have rectified it. Yet to find the solu to the actual prob though

Comment: wow wow wow..... your solution works like a charm here DragonSamu..... only one problem.... everytime i get a open file window for everycell and has to cancel the window for the program to proceed futher

Comment: ▲... and that's why I suggested keeping the formula local to the worksheet it was placed on and adding the full path after-the-fact.

Comment: @Jeeped agree, adjusting my answer thanks for the Tip :)

Comment: @ShikharParashar see update in the Edit part. Removed `_Loc_` and `Replace` is now "$C$17"

Comment: @ShikharParashar - remember to review [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @ShikharParashar don't forget to accept the answer and upvote of you think its good :)