# How to overcome the max length limit of a formula in Excel? a bug of excel?

Tags: excel

There are at least two forms of formula in Excel. One is used for cells, and the other is used for data validation. The max length limit for the formula to do data validation is about only 210 chars.

Here is a problem I am trying to solve. Given a data set with categories and values

```
category   value1   value2
a           1.0     ...
a           2.0
a           1.0
a           3.0
b           1.0
b           5.0
b           2.0     ...
...
```

I want to validate these values by checking if the value change from the row above is within one sigma deviation of its category. That means we need to skip the first row of each category.

Here is what I tried:

The following formula works for cells of each category beginning from the second row to the last row of its category.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())) - INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN())) < 
1.0*STDDEV.P(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()), $A:$A, 0), COLUMN()) & ":" &ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()),$A:$A, 1), COLUMN())))
```

However, the following doesn't work because of the max length limit of formula in excel - just add IF(formula_above, True, False):

```
=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())) - INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN())) < 
1.0*STDDEV.P(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()), $A:$A, 0), COLUMN()) & ":" &ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()),$A:$A, 1), COLUMN()))), TRUE, FALSE)
```

This can work if one input the formula into a cell, but it doesn't work for the refer-to formula of Data Validation.

To work with all cells all rows (without need to manully skip the first row of each category), I wrote following formula for data validation. But it gives "The FOrmula currently evaluates to an error..." because of the max length limit of the excel.

```
=IF(MATCH(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()), $A:$A, 0) = ROW(), TRUE,
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())) - INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN())) < 
1.0*STDDEV.P(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()), $A:$A, 0), COLUMN()) & ":" &ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()),$A:$A, 1), COLUMN()))))
```

Although Microsoft claims that the length limit of formula of excel is "8192", it seems not true:
https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

**Update:**

Here is another try for the formula of "Data Validation":

```
=IF($A2<>$A1, TRUE, abs(B2-B1)<Stdev.P(offset(indirect(address(match($A2,$A:$A,0), column())), 0,0,countif($A:$A, $A2,1)))
```

It is strange that the True/False value of the formula above is correct when I input in a cell, but when I input it in the "Data Validation" ->Custom -> Formula. The result is completely wrong. It always gives False.

Comment: Are you using vba `Formula` or pasting the `Formula` into `Excel`? If pasting into `Excel` look at: [Formula vba limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495311/adjusting-the-formula-in-formulaarray/32495582#32495582)

Comment: I don't use VBA formula. But the formula for data validation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Excel 2010 you can enter max 255 chars in data validation formula.

You can simplify your formula to fit the limits.

Instead of using:

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()))
```

You can simply use cell relative address.

Select e.g. `B2:B50` and enter validation formula:

```
=IF($A2<>$A1,TRUE,B2-B1<STDEV.P(IF($A:$A=$A2,B:B)))
```

This should be equivalent to your formula.

> within one sigma deviation of its category

I think you may need to use `ABS(B2-B1)` instead of `B2-B1`.

**EDIT:**

Your screenshot to prove that my formula is not working as expected:

[image: screenshot]

Please enter the same formula, but confirm it with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`. Now it's an array formula, with different result (10).

You can't confirm formula entered in data validation field with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`, but you don't need to do it. Excel parses every formula in data validation as an array formula.

Below is the screenshot of sample data with data validation applied:

[image]

On the right you can see a table with standard deviation of all cells, and each category. *Circle invalid cells* option highlights cells that do not meet criteria. As you can see different deviation is applied to each category.

Comment: Cool! That's right. I need to add abs(B2-B1). However, the standard deviation range is not right. "IF($A:$A=$A2,B:B)", I don't want to select the whole column, but only the rows of the same category.

Comment: my approach is also not working as expected, because of the match type, when the first column is grouped but not sorted.

Comment: @Rex `STDEV.P(IF($A:$A=$A2,B:B)))` calculates the standard deviation only for the current category (and it works even if the list in not sorted). However if the list is not sorted, you should change the outer `IF` condition to check for the first element of the category.

Comment: I took a screen shot. This shows the summation over 'IF($A:$A=$A2,B:B)'  does not select the row of the same category, but the whole column.

Comment: Confirmed! What is the magic of ctrl+shift+enter? It put an "{}" outside of the formula

Comment: @Rex it is called "array formula", it is very useful on many occasions. You should google it to learn some basics.

Comment: It works. But it takes more than 5 minutes to validate 10k cells. Is there any way to boost it? The formula in my post can do the validation almost instantly. The problem was the first row of each category. I need to clear the validation of them in manual.

Comment: @Rex yes, do not use full columns in the formulas, just the ranges that contain data. 10k is less than 1M.

Comment: @Rex if it doesn't help - you should create separate question. This one was about formula length limit, not performance. If you do - please describe you real data distribution (sorting, grouping)