# What is the fastest way to boost the performance of this Excel formula?

Tags: excel

This is to go further from the following post.

[How to overcome the max length limit of a formula in Excel? a bug of excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604740/how-to-overcome-the-max-length-limit-of-a-formula-in-excel-a-bug-of-excel/32605808#32605808)

Here is a problem I am trying to solve. Given a data set with categories and values

```
category   value1   value2
a           1.0     ...
a           2.0
a           1.0
a           3.0
b           1.0
b           5.0
b           2.0     ...
...
```

I want to validate these values by checking if the value change from the row above is within one sigma deviation of its category. That means we need to skip the first row of each category.

**Here is what I tried:**

The following formula works for cells of each category beginning from the second row to the last row of each category.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())) - INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN())) < 
1.0*STDDEV.P(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()), $A:$A, 0), COLUMN()) & ":" &ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()),$A:$A, 1), COLUMN())))
```

It works pretty fast, but we need to clear the data validation for the first row of each category.

**Here is a solution provided by @user3964075**

```
{=IF($A2<>$A1,TRUE,B2-B1<STDEV.P(IF($A:$A=$A2,B:B)))}
```

The problem is the performance. It need more than ten minutes for 200Kb data set.

What is the fastest formula to do this?

Comment: The performance of the array formula is bad because it includes all rows in columns `A` and `B` until max row 1048576. It should be much faster if you could limit the max row. Example: `{=IF($A2<>$A1,TRUE,B2-B1<STDEV.P(IF($A$1:$A$1000=$A2,B$1:B$1000)))}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beyond the `STDDEV.P` ([STDEV.P function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-P-function-6E917C05-31A0-496F-ADE7-4F4E7462F285)...?) in the original question, the flagrant use of volatile¹ functions in underlying processes like data validation has got to be killing your calculation cycles. Substituting for array formulas² with full column references is not helping.

### Using Dynamic Named Ranges

The following method is going to create some dynamic named ranges. There will be one for the contiguous data block 'island' originating in A1 and others that will reference column A on whatever row you use them as well as cells above whatever cell it is being used in and the range from which the [STDEV.P function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-P-function-6E917C05-31A0-496F-ADE7-4F4E7462F285) will be getting its returned result.

While there is not much point in using these beyond the worksheet for which they are intended, they will be given Workbook (as opposed to worksheet) scope. I cannot see anywhere that the worksheet was actually named so I will work with **Sheet2**. Adjust the worksheet name if necessary. Note that you will being using varying combinations of absolute and relative columns and rows in the cell range references.

1. Select A2 on Sheet2. This is **IMPORTANT!**
2. Go to Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name Manager. When the **Name Manager** dialog opens, click <kbd>New</kbd> to create each of these named ranges.
3. **stdCAT** - Will reference the cell in column A that corresponds to whatever row it is being used on.


   - Name: stdCAT
   - Scope: Workbook
   - Refers to: `=Sheet2!$A2`
4. **stdVALa** - Will reference the actual cell that the formula it assists is in.


   - Name: stdVALa
   - Scope: Workbook
   - Refers to: `=Sheet2!A2`
5. **stdVALb** - Will reference the cell above the cell that the formula it assists is in.


   - Name: stdVALb
   - Scope: Workbook
   - Refers to: `=Sheet2!A1`
6. **stdDATA** - Will reference the data island extending right from A1 for as many cells as there are in row 1 and down from A1 for as many cells as there are in column A.


   - Name: stdDATA
   - Scope: Workbook
   - Refers to: `=Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$Z, MATCH("zzz", Sheet2!$A:$A), MATCH("zzz", Sheet2!$1:$1))`
7. **stdRNG** - Will reference the extents of the range of data in the current column from the row containing the first instance of the associated in columnA to the last.


   - Name: stdRNG
   - Scope: Workbook
   - Refers to: `=INDEX(stdDATA, MATCH(Sheet2!$A2, Sheet2!$A:$A, 0), COLUMN()):INDEX(stdDATA, MATCH(Sheet2!$A2, Sheet2!$A:$A, 1), COLUMN())`
8. When these named ranges have been created, click <kbd>Close</kbd> in the lower-right to return to your worksheet.

Select `Sheet2!B3:B8` (from your sample data) and choose Data ► Data Tools ► Data Validation. Opt for **Allow: Custom** and supply the following for the **Source:**,

```
=(stdVALa-stdVALb)<STDEV.P(stdRNG)
```

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to create the Data Validation Rule. Select other ranges and create other Data Validation Rules as necessary.

What you've accomplished is a complete bypass of the **No reference operators** data validation restriction and you've done this without resorting to volatile¹ functions or array formulas² with full column references. Each named range and its subsequent calculation load when used in a formula is only as large as it absolutely has to be. The full column references used in the [MATCH functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) will not negatively impact the calculation load as by their very nature the *lookup_value* has to be found.

You should be able to recognize close similarities with the resulting formula and your original method and that is by design. It was not my intention to provide a new formula so much as to redesign the working model to a more efficient version.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [ADDRESS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-D0C26C0D-3991-446B-8DE4-AB46431D4F89), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566) and [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592).</sub>

² <sub>Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically as their referenced cell ranges grow. Always try to keep any cell range references to an absolute minimum when used in an array formula.</sub>

Comment: The formula I provided above may benefit from the `=IF($A2<>$A1,TRUE,...` additional wrapper suggested by @user3964075.

Comment: Great explanation of dynamic named ranges and a solution obviously outperforming full column array formulas. But I'm curious about one thing: in this particular case (data validation) is there any benefit of using non volatile functions?

Comment: I am interested in any performance gain as well but not quite interested enough to set up the '200Kb data set' that the OP has described. Hopefully they will share their experience along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

The performance of the array formula is bad because it includes all rows in columns A and B until max row 1048576. It should be much faster if you could limit the max row. Example:

```
{=IF($A2<>$A1,TRUE,B2-B1<STDEV.P(IF($A$1:$A$1000=$A2,B$1:B$1000)))}
```

To increase the performance further, you could use helper columns for calculating of standard deviation.

Example:
[image]

Formula in `F2` downwards and sidewards:

```
{=IF($A2<>$A1,STDEV.P(IF($A$1:$A$100000=$A2,B$1:B$100000)),F1)}
```

This is an array formula. Put it into the cell without the curly brackets and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm.

With this formula the `STDEVP(IF($A$1:$A$100000=$A2,B$1:B$100000))` needs only to be calculated if the category changes in column `A`. This should be much fewer times as if it must be calculated for each row.

The formula for the validation in `B2:En` has then to be:

```
=IF($A2<>$A1,TRUE,B2-B1<F2)
```