# FormulaArray command not working for formula with less than 255 characters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I already did a similar post with a `.FormulaArray` command which wasn't working and it turned out I had to replace the formula with some variable because it won't hold more than 255 characters.

All of a sudden, formula doesn't work anymore, and I managed to reduce the length of original formula to 227 characters. I thought it would work fine but it doesn't neither with straight code nor replacement.

The code I have is:

```
Sheets("BD MXN").Range("R2:R" & last).FormulaArray = "=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(('BD MXN'!$X$2:$X$50000='Acum MXN'!Q2)*('BD MXN'!$Q$2:$Q$50000='Acum MXN'!O2)*('BD MXN'!$W$2:$W$50000='Acum MXN'!P2)*('BD MXN'!$O$2:$O$50000='Acum MXN'!A2),'BD MXN'!$A$2:$A$50000),'BD MXN'!$A$2:$A$50000)>0))"
```

What I do is to count unique results considering different criteria, formula works perfect if I copy it and paste it, then hitting Ctrl + Shift + Enter, however nothing would work on VBA code.

Any workaround will be much appreciated.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. Did this exact formula ever work through VBA?  I'm pretty certain that the 255 character limit relates to the number of characters if the formula was using **R1C1** notation. If you translate your formula, it then has 268 characters.  If I shorten it (and I did that by shortening the sheet names), so that it has less than 255 in R1C1 notation, then the VBA FormulaArray property works.  So you'll either have to shorten this further, or split it up as you did with the other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495311/adjusting-the-formula-in-formulaarray/32495582#32495582

Comment: The formula is on sheet "BD MXN" so you can remove that reference from the formula.

Comment: Further to what @TimWilliams mentioned, we can create named ranges as well for `$X$2:$X$50000`, `$Q$2:$Q$50000` etc

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I didn't know it had to be less than 255 chars with R1C1 notation. Now it works like a charm avoiding reference to the same sheet I'm already refering to.